Docker exec with python subprocess.Popen failes
Objective
Use docker exec on an EC2 instance to run a command in another container that is on the instance.
Code:
from base64 import decode
import json
import subprocess


with open('temp.json', 'r') as file:
    event = json.load(file)
encoded = json.dumps(event)

a = ['/usr/bin/docker', 'exec', '-it', '4015980c98fb', 'python',  '-m', 'code.handler', encoded]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with subprocess.Popen(a, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) as test:
        print(f'ARGS: {test.args}')
        for line in test.stdout:
            line = line.decode().strip()
            print(line)

Observed Behavior
On Local Machine: The subprocess is correctly initiated and run
AWS ECS: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Is docker running? From inside the running ECS task:

root@532795fd1aad:/# docker -h
Flag shorthand -h has been deprecated, use --help

Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND

A self-sufficient runtime for containers

Common Commands:
  run         Create and run a new container from an image
...

shell=True
Usage text is printed locally and in AWS ECS but the command appears correct:
ARGS: ['/usr/bin/docker', 'exec', '-it', '4015980c98fb', 'python', '-m', 'code.handler' '{...}',
Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND

A self-sufficient runtime for containers

Options:
--config string      Location of client config files (default "/home/michael/.docker")
-c, --context string     Name of the context to use to connect to the daemon (overrides DOCKER_HOST env var and default context set with "docker context
use")
...

What am I missing/not understanding here?

You probably can't use the Docker API on ECS, or other cluster environments like Kubernetes.  (Using it at all has very large security consequences: you can all but trivially take over the host machine.)  You usually wouldn't want to docker exec as part of an automated task in any case, any more than you'd want to "go inside" this Python program as it's running; do you want to run this other Python module via an ordinary function call, or as a subprocess, or in a new container (you'd have to use an ECS-specific API for this)?

Also see Can an ECS container have access to the docker socket?  But note that it's not necessarily possible, and your process will gain the ability to interfere with other containers or the host.

@DavidMaze Thanks for the info. I am trying to write code that orchestrates the processing of inputs through a number of ECS tasks. The idea is that I have containers that are already setup to use docker exec and docker run so I want to use that to do the processing.

Something like a message queue (RabbitMQ or Kafka in open-source land, maybe SQS if you don't mind being tied to Amazon's infrastructure) is often a better match for this.  I'd generally reserve docker exec for actual debugging, and I'd avoid using the Docker API or CLI tools if you can.  (How would you distribute these tasks around the cluster?)

You're trying to run docker from inside a docker container started by ECS? Or from the host EC2 instance? It looks like you are trying to run it from inside the container, which explains why it isn't finding the docker process. You would want to run it from the host. Although, since you are using ECS, you should probably be using ECS Exec instead of Docker exec https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/new-using-amazon-ecs-exec-access-your-containers-fargate-ec2/

@MarkB I am trying to run it from within the container. I initially tried using the boto3 ecs.execute_command but it can't handle long: responses:https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3496. To work around this I install the AWS CLI in the container and run exec execute-command from the CLI and there is noticeable overhead to doing this. I have container a b, ..., n where a orchestrates the processing of inputs through each container. I may need to look into the message queue approach mentioned by David though.

If you are in the same container you are trying to run a command in, why not just directly run the command? I don't understand the point of running docker exec from within the container itself.

@MarkB I am not trying to run the command in the same container. I have a "main" container that tries to use docker exec in several other containers on the instance.
